# Get values of jsonarray using other jsonarray values as a key

Tags: java, json, org.json

I'm getting following json from server:

```
{
"Data": [
    {
        "Record": [
            " d11",
            "d12"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Record": [
            " d21",
            "d22"
        ]
    }
],
"Keys": [
    "Key1",
    " key2"
]
```

}

I want to retrieve **record** values which are **ordered** with respect to **keys** values(key1, key2?

Note: Using org.json api only.

Comment: First of all, I don't think that JSON is valid. Is the data supposed to be an object rather than a list? And are the keys in the list supposed to match the keys of the data object?

Comment: Its a valid json.. We have implemented like.. Keys are database columns..and value array(data1 & data2) has d11 d12 & d21 d22 which are respective values of columns.. Each data1 & data2 is individual rows... We've used arraylist to ensure insertion order.. Note: we have to avoid putting key:value pair at server side.. Hence Required to Seek to parse this JSON at client side..

Comment: @andersschuller thanks for figuring it out.. I've updated the correct json.. Problem persists..

Comment: @andersschuller yes.. Keys in the list are supposed to match keys in data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is still a little unclear to me, but I'm assuming you want to turn that JSON into a list of records, where each record is (for example) a map containing the keys from the list of keys and the values from the data list.

In order to achieve this, we first parse the JSON into a `JSONObject`:

```
String json = " ... ";
JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(json);
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(tokener);
```

Then we extract the list  of keys and the data list:

```
JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Data");
JSONArray keys = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Keys");
```

and define a list to contain our output:

```
List<Map<String, String>> records = new ArrayList<>();
```

Finally, we iterate over the data list, extract the list of record values for each item in that list, and then iterate over the keys in order to create a map from key to record value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject dataItem = data.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONArray recordValues = dataItem.getJSONArray("Record");

    Map<String, String> record = new HashMap<>();

    for (int j = 0; j < keys.length(); j++) {
        String key = keys.getString(j);
        String value = recordValues.getString(j);
        record.put(key, value);
    }

    records.add(record);
}
```

When we then print the value of `records`, we get something that looks like:

```
[{Key1= d11,  key2=d12}, {Key1= d21,  key2=d22}]
```